# C# Server closing/crashing if a client connects to it when the server lost focus (ex. screensaver is running)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I am writing a client-server application using TCP Sockets. The server is written in C# using Visual Studio 2010 (.NET 4.0). The server allows multiple client connections at the same time therefore I am using the Async. style. The server needs to connect to a database (MySQL) and while the server program is running I need to interact with the database. For this reason I am using a BackgroundWorker to run the infinite listening loop (that will Accept Clients) in order to prevent the interface from freezing and be able to access the database from the visual interface.

Everything is working fine unless when the server program losses focus. Examples of losing focus are: the PC that is running the server program starts the screensaver, you click on the clock on the task-bar to see the time, you open another widow (windows explorer, calculator...). If the server program looses focus and a client tries to connect, the server closes completely! If I am running the server from Visual Studio it does not throw any error or exception. If I am running a released version of the server, Microsoft Windows will show the "Programming not responding..." dialog.

Here is how my code is structured:

Variables in the main class:

```
const int portNo  = 12345;
static System.Net.IPAddress localAdd = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.67");
static TcpListener tcpListenerReadWrite  = new TcpListener(localAdd, portNo);
```

In the main Form a button starts the server:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tcpListenerReadWrite.Start();
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

The background worker DoWork function:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    while (true)
    {
        ChatClient clientRead = new ChatClient(tcpListenerReadWrite.AcceptTcpClient());
    }
}
```

In the Server Class, the constructor is as follows:

```
public ChatClient(TcpClient client) //constructor
{
    _client = client;
    _clientIP = client.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString();

    //start reading data from the client in a separate thread
    data = new byte[_client.ReceiveBufferSize];
    _client.GetStream().BeginRead(data, 0, Convert.ToInt32(_client.ReceiveBufferSize), ReceiveMessage, client);
}
```

When a message is received by the server:

```
public void ReceiveMessage(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
{
    //read received message from client
}
```

Two final notes: (1) when a client connects to the server the first thing it does is sending a message to the server like a Hello message, (2) before writing the server in a visual interface I was testing it in a Console mode and this problem was not existing, the screensaver used to run and nothing happened. Sure in the console mode I didn't use any BackgroundWorker.

Any ideas why the server is crashing?

Comment: i am unable to reproduce that behaviour ... can you post a minimal working sample with that bahaviour?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you, you need me to post more detailed code or you need a better explanation of the situation? :)

Comment: a code sample ... 1) the code sample should reproduce the error 2) the code sample should be minimal (no code that has nothing to do with this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what was crashing my server (it took me some time because I was lately focusing on the client programming, it is today when I returned to the server programming). As @Moo-Juice suggested, it is a problem related to accessing the UI. In fact here is the scenario that was causing the crash:

1. The server starts
2. It enters into an infinite loop listening for clients to connect. This infinite loop is in the `backgroundWorker`.
3. A client connects to the server.
4. I print a message on a `textBox` that a client has connected. **//here is the problem**
5. To be able to establish point (4) I am using the `backgroundWorker.ReportProgress` method.

To review the problem, the server crashes **only** if the focus is not on the program (a screen saver is running for example), but no crashing if the focus is on the program and logging is working. When I stopped the logging things went OK. So know I know the source of the problem but I don't know why it is causing the crash; as I know the `ReportProgress` is designed to be use to report progress to the user interface. Anyway I will try to solve this now especially that I know from where to go. In case you are interested to see how I was doing the logging here is the function that I used:

```
private void PrintString(string stringToPrint)
{
    var myForm = Form1.ActiveForm as Form1;
    myForm.backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(1, stringToPrint);
}
```

And here is the `ReportProgress` function:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text += (string)e.UserState;
    textBox1.Text += Environment.NewLine;
}
```

Nothing so fancy but enough to cause me headache :) Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Got it again :) The problem in my function `PrintString` is that I was reaching the `backgroundWorker` which is on another file through `form1`. Well as we all know we are not allowed to touch components from another thread and `form1` is from the UI thread, this caused the crash. The solution was that on connecting to a new client I passed the `backgroundWorker` to the constructor of the client creation (`ChatClient`) which in turn saved it in a global `backgroundWorker` variable, and in `PrintString` I no more need to get through `form1` to reach the worker, I simply use the global one.

Answer (score 2):

Has it got anything to do with the TcpListener being created on the main UI thread and not your Background thread?  You said yourself that this does not happen in a Console application.  I suspect that since you have some UI elements involved now, it's not as clear cut.

My suggestion is to move *ALL* of your networking outside of the UI thread, and not in the 'main' class.  Have it completely independent.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have a class that deals with all the networking, I moved all the network related stuff from my main class to this class where I inserted them in a new constructor. Now in the BackgroundWorker I only create an object from my NetworkClass which calls the new constructor, but the problem is still there. Is that what you meant by "outside the UI thread" or I got you wrong?

Comment: @antf, my question is...  not so much where the data members are (e.g. what classes they are in), but in what thread they are being instantiated and *used*.  From the examples you posted, it's not overly clear to me.  Whilst I am unsure why you are experiencing this behaviour, I am pretty sure it has something to do with a UI Thread vs background thread mixup.  Otherwise your console application would have bailed aswell. :)